# Javascript function can console.log the value but not return it

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects:

```
let array = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: "Name0"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Name1"
  }
]
```

and a function that iterates through the array, searches for the object with a specified id property and should return the objects name property:

```
function getName1(id) {
  array.map((object) => {
    if(object["id"] === id)
      return object["name"]
  })
}
```

However this code

```
console.log(getName1(0)) // undefined
```

returns undefined

If I simply console.log the name of the object inside the function

```
function getName2(id) {
  array.map((object) => {
    if(object["id"] === id)
      console.log(object["name"])
  })
}
```

it works perfectly fine:

```
getName2(0) // "Name1"
```

I basically just want

```
getName1(0)
```

to return

```
Name0
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please use only appropriate tags. This has nothing to do with [tag:asynchronous] or [tag:undefined], and arguably not really to do with [tag:return] either.

Comment: Your function getName1 isn't returning anything.  The return statement is in map not in the getName1 function.  You need to iterate the array looking for the match then return that value.  I don't think map is what you want here.  Check out reduce or just iterate the array

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your `return` statement is returning from the `map` callback, not from `getName1`.

You shouldn't be using `map` at all, its job is to create a new array based on the return values of the callback.

Instead, use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), whose job is to find the first entry in the array where the given callback function returns a truthy value, and then return the `name` property of the found entry if any:

```
function getName1(id) {
    const entry = array.find(object => object.id === id);
    return entry && entry.name;
}
```

Or in ES5 and earlier (I used ES2015+ above because you used an arrow function):

```
function getName1(id) {
    var entry = array.find(function(object) { return object.id === id; });
    return entry && entry.name;
}
```

The `entry && entry.name` part means "If `entry` is truthy, return `entry.name`; otherwise, return `entry` (the falsy value) itself." In this case, it will return `null` if the entry wasn't found (because that's what `Array#find` returns when the entry isn't found) or the `name` of the found entry.

Comment: Thank you very much! I totally "forgot" that I am using map.. sometimes you just go blind after some time I guess :)

If I understand correctly, the "old-school" way of getting what I wanted would be to just loop through the array ( `for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i ++) {...search for name corresponding to id and return it...}` but you are making use of the find method on the array object which makes it more concise

Thanks again, case closed :)

Comment: @Skilla123: Yes, that would indeed be another way to do it.